Compilation Error: Illegal character: '\uFEFF'
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class hindi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        for(i=2309;i<=2362;i++)
        System.out.println(i+":"+(char)i);
    }
}

I want to print all the hindi characters have tried running this code in vs code but this is showing error like this-
error: illegal character: '\\ufeff'
````````` ?import java.util.*; ^ hindi.java:1: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected ?import java.util.*;         ^ hindi.java:2: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected import java.lang.*; ^ hindi.java:3: error: class, interface, enum, or record expected import java.io.*; ^``your text `



seems like the editor is adding an UTF-16 BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the start of your text (some Windows programs like to do that, even for UTF-8) - How was the file edited? Which encoding is it set up to use?

encoding is UTF-8 only

Prefer System.out.println(i+":" + Character.toString(i)); For some codepoints, you won't be able to cast to char without data loss and then you'll get the wrong character

Please don't replace your question with a different one after it has been answered. Ask a new question instead.

There is a special character called the Byte-Order-Mark or BOM.
It has some really funky properties:

It looks like nothing. Not even space. It takes no room at all and has no meaning.

It's a character (just like 'c', or ' ' (space), or a newline, or 'ç', or ☃ or even ). Just, looks like nothing.

In bytes, its value is 0xFE 0xFF.

Uniquely, 0xFF 0xFE does not exist in any way - 0xFEFF is like a hole punched into the paper on a big board of characters. 0xFEFF (BOM) is a character that looks like nothing. 0xFFFE does not exist.


The point of all this bizarreness?
Some computer systems ('little endian' ones) treat the first data it means as the least significant. Basically, they write in reverse. "1234" is written as "4321". Others treat the first data as the most significant.
This can lead to data that cannot be read; you need to know the byte ordering to read it. Fortunately, if the file so happens to start with the BOM character, now you know. Because if it starts with the byte sequence 0xFE FF, it's in big endian byte order. If it's 0xFF FE, it's in little endian order. That's because there is no character with code 0xFFFE.
However, this is an aspect of UTF-16 and UTF-32 which are outdated, borderline obsolete storage strategies. UTF-8 is far more common and doesn't need it. Java does not allow BOMs in its spec.
Your editor added one, and javac therefore tells you the file is invalid.
How do I fix this
I dunno: Check your editor, tell it to stop writing a BOM. If you can configure the charset encoding, config it to emit UTF-8.

It is already set to UTF - 8 . it is still giving the same error.what to do ?

do I need to do anychanges in settings or add some extensions?

Your editor is emitting a BOM even though that is a rather silly thing to do when emitting UTF-8. What editor are you using? VSCode doesn't normally add these; perhaps the file already has one and VSCode is neither adding nor removing it. Use a hex editor, or just copy paste the contents to a new file. Leave out the first character (presumably, the p from package) and re-add it after pasting to be sure.

2309:?
2310:?
2311:?
2312:?
2313:?
2314:?
2315:?
2316:?
2317:?
2318:?
2319:?
2320:?
2321:?
2322:?
2323:?
2324:?
2325:?
2326:?
2327:?
2328:?
2329:?
2330:?
2331:?
2332:?
2333:?
2334:?
2335:?
2336:?
2337:?
2338:?
2339:?
2340:?
2341:?
2342:?
2343:?
2344:?
2345:?
2346:?
2347:?
2348:?
2349:?
2350:?
2351:?
2352:?
2353:?
2354:?
2355:?
2356:?
2357:?
2358:?
2359:?
2360:?
2361:?
2362:?

now it is printing "?" instead of hindi characters

also i have not used all the imports before. i am using it first time

You need to configure your terminal and viewer to also be uTF-8. We can't help you without knowing precisely what OS, editor, terminal, you use, and every setting. Which sounds like a bit much for SO. Perhaps search the web. If your code as above now compiles, the problem is not your java code. That's fine. Its not your editor either. It's your terminal and/or font.

Yea ... fixing your (Windows?) console so that it understands Hindi characters and/or UTF-8 is not on-topic for StackOverflow.  I'm guessing Windows because adding a gratuitous BOM is the kind of thing that (AFAIK) only Windows editors do.

I am using vs code only

how to configure terminal and viewer to utf-8. explain steps

it is windows 11
